# What are the prerequisites for Hybrid Boot?

Tags: windows-8

I was curious about trying Hybrid Boot, or to see if I'd already been using it. It turns out I don't even have the option to enable it available to me.

[image: Windows 8 Shutdown Settings]

What does Windows need to do a hybrid shutdown/boot?

Comment: It could simply be disabled. Try executing `powercfg -h on`.

Comment: @Dennis Ah, if it requires hibernation, I think I'll leave it off.

Comment: A hybrid shutdown essentially means hibernating after logging off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast startup requires hibernation to be enabled. If you have the correct drivers installed but you still don't see the setting, you can try to enable hibernation by opening `Command Prompt` as an administrator and running `powercfg /hibernate on`.

[image: Command Prompt]

When hibernation is enabled, you should see the `Turn on fast startup (recommended)` option.

[image: Hibernate is enabled]

Answer (score 2):

As [MSFN post](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/152937-what-is-hybrid-boot-in-windows-8-and-how-does-it-work/) suggests

> To use Hybrid boot, your system must have a hibernation file and the drivers must support hibernation.

I think the unsupported drivers is the root of the problem in your case. It will take some time to update all the drivers to the new technology.